# Stop Windows update windows from hiding

Tags: windows-update

I like to keep an eye on the updates coming in from Windows Update, so I have it set to notify me of updates but not install anything automatically. When I'm notified, I usually just select all of the updates and click install. Then the window hides itself, and a little balloon on the taskbar says Windows is updating and I can click it to view the progress.

I always want to view the progress and get annoyed that it hides the window **every** time. Can I turn off this auto-hide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore the notification icon, and manually startup the Windows Update program (e.g. from the *All Programs* list or *Control Panel*).  You may have to first "check for updates".  Select and then download & install the updates.  The program window will not auto minimize.

Comment: I was hoping for a registry key or something so I could keep using the notification, but opening it manually when I see the notification will have to do. Thanks.